# How to convert Future<List<Object>> to List<Object>?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm getting values from API and it's in a `Future<List<Object>>` form how do i convert into `List<Objects>`?

i already tried using Future Builder but it recursively return NoDataDialog Widget.

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to deal with async functions

**1st**

```
_asyncFunction() async {
  List list = await futureList;
}
```

**2nd**

```
_asyncFunction() {

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      //this executes
    }).then((_) {
      //then this
    });
}
```

Comment: The `//this executes first` and `//this waits to execute` comments do not make sense.  There is no waiting.  Any code placed at the `//this waits to execute` point will execute immediately without waiting for any `Future`s.

Comment: Your right I fixed it I thanks i don't want to be putting out wrong information